# Is it bad practice to hand over an initialized class to a new class?

Tags: python

If I have one class, which gets object as input, like this

```
class Polygons():
    def __init__(self, logical_graph: Graph):
        self.qbits = logical_graph.qubits_from_graph()
        self.K = len(self.qbits)
```

is this ok, or should Polygons() inherit from Graph(), and then use super().**init**() or something like that. What is the better style? The class Graph() may be initialized very specifically.

Comment: Prefer composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: If `Polygons` _is_ a `Graph` you _might_ use inheritance in all other cases you should not.

Comment: No, Polygons is not a graph, it is build from closed loops in a graph